# Variation on Service Locator

Tags: c#, generics, service-locator

```
IModificationRequst<Employee> req = new ModificationRequst();
Locator.Instance.GetService<IModificationRequstHandler<Employee>>().Handle(req);
```

I have a service locator that locates services that returns instances of objects implementing IModificationRequstHandler.

I am trying to modify it to rather than returning a IModificationRequstHandler implementer, it is just internally finds the service and invokes it's handler method, so the above 2 lines would look like this instead:

```
IModificationRequst<Employee> req = new ModificationRequst();
Locator.Instance.HandleRequest<IModificationRequst<Employee>>(req);
```

But having hard time with the generics, is there an already established pattern for resovling the requests to their proper request handlers and invoking their handling, rather than getting a handler and then invoking their Handle method from the client?

Comment: Out of interest, why aren't you injecting the implementation of IModificationRequst<Employee> into the class instead of using a Locator in the method.

Comment: @RobertSlaney : No special reason. This is how things are now, once get this problem might very well refactor that in .

Comment: If you inject in, this issue become null and void!.  You are basically wanting to implement the Command pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That violates Single Responsibility Principle. You should not make the service locator implement logic for different services.

If you do want to use static classes you should add another one:

```
public static class RequestHandler
{
    public static void Handle<T>(T request)
    {
        Locator.Instance.GetService<IModificationRequstHandler<T>>().Handle(req);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
IModificationRequst<Employee> req = new ModificationRequst();
RequestHandler.Handle(req);
```

(*Sidenote: You might look up [Dependency Injection & IoC containers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/386164/Get-injected-into-the-world-of-inverted-dependenci) since it makes the code more maintainable*)

Comment: using DI or IOC, what would be the equivalent question? I am happy to drop the Service Locator, but what is the replacement in this context?

Comment: @Arjang: Create a class which takes the container as a constructor parameter and use the container internally in that application (and register the new class in the container).

Answer (score 1):

Your `HandleRequest` method in the locator class should be defined as follows (assuming `Handle` has a return type of `void`):

```
public void HandleRequest<T>(IModificationRequest<T> req)
{
    IModificationRequstHandler<T> handler = GetService<IModificationRequest<T>>();
    handler.Handle(req);
}
```

and your `IModificationRequstHandler` interface should be defined as follows:

```
public interface IModificationRequstHandler<T>
{
    void Handle(IModificationRequst<T> req);
}
```

and your call will then become:

```
Locator.Instance.HandleRequest(req);
```

The generic type parameter `Employee` here is inferred from the parameter value `req` and thus does not need to be specified.

Comment: Thank you, but " // get handler somehow..." is how? tried using Locator.Instance.GetSerice<??>();

Comment: I'll edit, although it'll be a bit of a guess since I don't know what your `Locator.GetService()` method needs to be able to do (does it only get `IMethodRequestHandler`s?).

Comment: +1 Thank you. I ended up making a nother class that uses the service locator dude to SRP.